# Is magnetic flux always zero?

Tags: magnetic-fields, gauss-law

So I have a doubt regarding the equations of **Magnetic flux** and **Gauss' Law** for magnetic fields.

According to Gauss' Law for magnetic fields,
integral form of *div(**B**)* = $0$ can be written as:

$\oint \mathbf{B}.d\mathbf{a} = 0$

And magnetic flux through a surface is also defined as
$\iint \mathbf{B}.d\mathbf{S} = \Phi _{B}$

If we combine the two, does it mean that flux is always zero through the surface?  I believe $\iint$ and $\oint$ are the same thing (correct me if I am wrong) ?
What is the significance of $\Phi _{B}$ then?

Comment: You can think of the Gauss Law flux as a count of the number field lines leaving a closed surface.  Magnetic field lines always form closed loops.  So each line that comes in ( - flux ) must also go out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe ∬ and ∮ are the same thing (correct me if I am wrong)?

$\oint$ is a closed contour integral symbol while $\iint$ is a double integral symbol.

[Gauss's Law for magnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_magnetism) in integral form is

$$\unicode{x222F}_S\,\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{A}=0$$

which states that the magnetic flux through a *closed* (no boundary) surface is zero (there are no magnetic monopoles). The symbol $\unicode{x222F}_S$ indicates integration over the closed surface $S$.

The magnetic flux through a surface *bounded* by a closed countour is not necessarily  zero. For example, the [Maxwell-Faraday equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Maxwell%E2%80%93Faraday_equation) is (for a surface unchanging with time)

$$\oint_{\partial \Sigma} \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{l} = - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \iint_{\Sigma} \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{A}$$

where $\Sigma$ is the surface of integration bounded by the closed countour $\partial\Sigma$.

Comment: Shouldn't the surface integral over $\Sigma$ in the last equation be an $\iint$ symbol, for consistency with the notation conventions established earlier in this post?